# How to name optionmenu boxes in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

At the moment each option menu box replaces the previous one so if write ent1.get() i dont get the value within any box, how can i distinguish betweeen each optionmenu and therefor retrieve each value distinctly? Ideally calling them all by a different name decided by their position in the grid.

```
  for x in range (xval):#creating the matrix
        for y in range (yval):
            variable = StringVar(root)
            ent1 = OptionMenu(root, variable, *inputvalues)#creating the dropdown menus
            ent1.config(width=3)
            ent1.grid(row=(y+1), column=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly but if you are trying to create different StringVar's in a single loop, you could use the variable.format() method to make sure each `StringVar` is saved as a unique variable.

Thus the following loop will create StringVar's that are saved into variables `ent1`, `ent2`, `ent3`, etc. This will allow you to call them separately later on..

```
for x in range (xval):#creating the matrix
        for y in range (yval):
            variable = StringVar(root)
            ent["ent{0}"].format(y+1) = OptionMenu(root, variable, *inputvalues)#creating the dropdown menus
            ent["ent{0}"].format(y+1).config(width=3)
            ent["ent{0}"].format(y+1).grid(row=(y+1), column=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to keep track of the widgets and variables.

```
entries = {}
vars = {}
for x in range (xval):#creating the matrix
    for y in range (yval):
        variable = StringVar(root)
        entry = OptionMenu(root, variable, *inputvalues)
        entry.config(width=3)
        entry.grid(row=(y+1), column=x)
        entries[(x,y)] = entry
        vars[(x,y)] = variable
```